# excel vba: Specific data columns moving to the right

Tags: vba, excel

I am having trouble with writing a small code of VBA that does the following: In a huge dataset, search a particular column for entries that are obviously wrong (e.g. being above 50,when they should be from 1-10).I want this to find these entries,and copy alla the columns to the right of it and move them 3 columns further to the right.It is some sort of data cleaning.Thanks

Comment: Post your current code and describe what happens when you run it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you would need VBA. Lets say that column A should be populated with numbers between 1 and 10. And columns B,C and D are populated with other data.

1. Select cell E1 and put in the formula `=IF($A1>50,A1,"")` in the formula box and push CTRL + Enter.
2. Use the drag handle to copy the formula into cells F1, G1, and H1.
3. With cells E1 through H1 selected, double click on the drag handle of cell H1.